# Gitlab License Scanning excluding projects in Groups

Tags: gitlab, licensing

I have a group xyz in Gitlab and there are a,b,c,d,e projects(repo) inside the group xyz.
Now i want to apply license scanning policy on the group this will enforce the policy on the all the projects however i want to skip a,e projects(Repo).
How that can be done

Resolution of the above problem plus some reference link

Answer (score 0):

Take this below yaml file as reference
include:

- template: Security/License-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml

license_scanning:
stage: test
tags:
- aker_internal
needs:
- Version updates - compile version
dependencies: []
variables:
ASDF_JAVA_VERSION: openjdk-$CI_JAVA_RELEASE
ASDF_MAVEN_VERSION: $CI_MAVEN_VERSION
LM_JAVA_VERSION: $ASDF_JAVA_VERSION
LICENSE_FINDER_CLI_OPTS: '--recursive'
MAVEN_OPTS: ""
MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-DskipTests --batch-mode -ntp"
SETUP_CMD: "/opt/gitlab/custom_setup.sh"
before_script:
- |-
cat < "$SETUP_CMD"
# Install the versions of Maven and Java we use
asdf install maven $ASDF_MAVEN_VERSION
asdf install java $ASDF_JAVA_VERSION
# This is to workaround issue where a GitLab pipeline tries to download our modules from public repositories
# which does not happen when running the container outside of a pipeline:
mvn install ${MAVEN_CLI_OPTS} -Dmaven.test.skip=true -f "$MAVEN_ROOT" ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE:+-s "$MAVEN_ROOT/$MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE"}
EOF
chmod +x "$SETUP_CMD"
rules:
- !reference [.workflow_rules, standard_workflow]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).